# Flutter - change text opacity on press

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically I want to change the opacity of the text when it is clicked. Like when it is pressed, its opacity becomes 0.4 and once it is released, its opacity becomes 1.0. Currently I'm trying to use `AnimatedOpacity` and I can only change the opacity on tap.

```dart
double textOpacity = 1.0;
//some widgets
 AnimatedOpacity(
   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
   opacity: textOpacity,
   child: GestureDetector(
     child: Text(
       'Tap',
       style: TextStyle(
          color: CupertinoColors.systemBlue,
       ),
     ),
     onTap: () {
       setState(() => textOpacity = 0.4);
     }
  ),
),
```

I also tried

```dart
onForcePressStart: (details) =>
    setState(() => textOpacity = 0.4),
onForcePressEnd: (details) =>
    setState(() => textOpacity = 1.0),
```

but it didn't work.

Can any one help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: You could try `onTapDown` instead of `onTap`. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onTapDown.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments `onTapDown()`  and `OnTapCancel` will do the job.

This is the code:

---

```
double opacity= 1.0; //Initialise for the first time Widget build.
GestureDetector(
              onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                opacity = 0.4;
                print('tappedDown');
                setState(() {});
              },
              onTapCancel: () {
                opacity = 1.0;
                print('tapcancel');
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: AnimatedOpacity(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                opacity: opacity,
                child: Text('Your Text'),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 4):

There is ready-to-use solution:

```dart
CupertinoButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // any action
  },
  child: Text('Tap'),
)
```